# Flash of Unstyled Content (FOUC) when using gatsby with Emotion?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, server-side-rendering, emotion, fouc

I'm trying to add Emotion to an existing Gatsby static site. It's generally working great *except* that the server render doesn't actually render the styles. For a brief moment after loading, or forever if you have JavaScript disabled, only one `.js` file of global styles is visible.

I've tried the steps in https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/troubleshooting-common-errors around clearing the cache, making sure the modules are installed, and updating package versions to latest. No luck.

Is this a known issue that can be dealt with?

You can see the full repository at https://github.com/JoshuaKGoldberg/Goldblog/tree/945d0ca8501b3aa069ef44145e4d05daa35da505.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `@emotion/core`, which uses the `css` prop, but you're passing your style tokens to the `className` prop, which is how you would do it if you're using the `emotion` package that requires additional setup for server-side rendering to work. [See this page in the documentation for a comparison and more details](https://emotion.sh/docs/introduction).

The fix is to first remove your `css()` function calls around your style object literals:

```js
// replace this
export const header = css({
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    flexDirection: "row",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    marginTop: "1.5rem",
});

// with this
export const header = {
  display: "flex",
  alignItems: "center",
  justifyContent: "center",
  flexDirection: "row",
  flexWrap: "wrap",
  marginTop: "1.5rem",
}
```

Then replace `className` with `css` anywhere you're passing in an object or array that you want to work with Emotion:

```
// replace this
<header className={styles.header}>
  <h1 className={styles.heading}>
    <Link className={styles.headingLink} to={`/`}>
      {title}
    </Link>
  </h1>
  <Bio />
</header>

// with this
<header css={styles.header}>
  <h1 css={styles.heading}>
    <Link css={styles.headingLink} to={`/`}>
      {title}
    </Link>
  </h1>
  <Bio />
</header>
```

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I needed. Thank you!